# Pandas concat multi level index dataframes and merge same name columns within same level

Tags: python, pandas

I have two multi-level index dataframes. When I concat them, the same name columns become duplicated.

df1

```
Column
  col1 col2
     1    3
     2    4
```

I want to merge this with another df,

df2

```
Column
  col3
     5
     6
```

When I merge both using

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

The result comes:

```
Column      Column
  col1 col2   col3
     1    3      5
     2    4      6
```

What I want to get is:

```
Column      
  col1 col2 col3
     1    3    5
     2    4    6
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

EDIT:

```
print (df1)
  Column     
    col5 col2
0      1    3
1      2    4

print (df2)
  Column
    col1
0      5
1      6


df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

c = df.columns.tolist()
df = df.reindex(c[:1] + sorted(c[1:]), axis=1)
print (df)
  Column          
    col5 col1 col2
0      1    5    3
1      2    6    4
```

EDIT1: Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), add original non selected caolumns values by [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) and last change order by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
  Column              a     
    col2 col1 col5 col1 col3
0      1    5    3    5    4
1      2    6    4    7    7

cols = (df.xs('Column', drop_level=False, axis=1, level=0)
          .sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1).columns)
print (cols)
MultiIndex([('Column', 'col5'),
            ('Column', 'col2'),
            ('Column', 'col1')],
           )

df = df.reindex(cols.union(df.columns, sort=False), axis=1)
print (df)
  Column              a     
    col5 col2 col1 col1 col3
0      3    1    5    5    4
1      4    2    6    7    7
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it changes the order of my columns. There is just one particular column I want to keep as the first column and rest can be in sorted order

Comment: @Ronnie - do you think first column from `df1` after `concat` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to retain the first column in df1 on its position after concat. That column is not common between two data frames so is there a way to sort the other columns leaving behind the first column? let's say the name of the column is 'FirstColumn'. Thanks

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. Just one more thing, is there a way I can sort the level 2 columns further? Which, according to the above example, are `col1 col2 col3`. Thank you so much

Comment: @Ronnie - Do you think all columns like `.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)` ? Or column after first, so sorting `sorted(c[1:])` by second level?

Comment: @Ronnie - .. so need `sorted(c[1:], key = lambda x: x[1])` ?

Comment: I have `col1 col2 col3` under `Column`, so I want to sort them in desc order so they would be in order `col3 col2 col1`. I have multiple columns on level 1 i.e. on `Column` level. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)
```